# What does a buffer object, and attribute pointer look like for changing vertex data

Tags: swift, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I was wondering what the proper practice doing the following would be.

So basically all I have is a array holding the coordinates of a cube.  Then as time goes on I change the values of the coordinates however do not change the size of the array.  I am trying to get things going as efficiently as possible!

A lot of places have talked theoretically about what something like this would look like.  However they never include data about passing attributes to the shader.  I have never understood how the attribute passing thing knows what buffer to look at.

Also please note that at the end of drawing I need to make things so all the streaming things and buffers that would get in the way of other drawing are properly disabled.  Here is what I have so far I think it is probably not the most efficient.

```
var locArray:[GLfloat] = []
var colArray:[GLfloat] = []
var sizeArray:[GLfloat] = []
var bObjColor:GLuint = 0
var bObjSize:GLuint = 0
var bObjVertex:GLuint = 0

var aLocColor:GLuint = 0
var aLocSize:GLuint = 0
var aLocVertex:GLuint = 0
func init() //Called on initializations
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &bObjColor)
    glGenBuffers(1, &bObjSize)
    glGenBuffers(1, &bObjVertex)

    aLocColor = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(pointShader, "color"))
    aLocSize = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(pointShader, "size"))
    aLocVertex = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(pointShader, "vertex"))
}
func draw() //Called on each frame
{
    editTheVertexData() // I didnt show because it does what it says
    build()
    draw()
    cleanup()
}
func build()
{
   glUseProgram(pointShader)
   glUniformMatrix4fv(uLocOrtho, 1, GLboolean(GL_FALSE), &matrix)

   glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), bObjColor)
   glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(GLfloat) * maxParticles * 8, colArray, GLenum(GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW))
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(aLocColor)
   glVertexAttribPointer(aLocColor, 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))


   glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), bObjSize)
   glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(GLfloat) * maxParticles * 2, sizeArray, GLenum(GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW))
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(aLocSize)
   glVertexAttribPointer(aLocSize, 1, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))

   glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), bObjVertex)
   glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(GLfloat) * maxParticles * 6, locArray, GLenum(GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW))
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(aLocVertex)
   glVertexAttribPointer(aLocVertex, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))


}
func draw()
{
    glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_POINTS), 0, 1000)
}
func cleanup()
{
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(aLocVertex)
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(aLocSize)
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(aLocColor)
}
```

How am I doing? I am guessing that somehow OpenGL can hold a pointer to the array and so I dont need to call glBuffer data each frame.  But I really dont know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should call `glBufferSubData` to reuse the memory on the GPU. But you do need to call something to send the data to the buffer.

So generally the buffers will allocate memory on the GPU or at least somewhere optimal for the GPU to use it. The buffers are generally used to send the data to the GPU and then keep reusing them. If you keep sending the data to the GPU you will not gain much performance if any at all. If you do find yourself in the situation where you update the buffer data on every frame you should most likely use `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. Check some documentation on these.

So generating a buffer will create a unique identifier for the API context to access the buffer. After that you should call `glBufferData` which is used to allocate the buffer data and has an optional pointer to send the data directly to the buffer. So the pointer parameter may be `NULL` and only memory will be allocated. To communicate with the buffer you usually have 2 procedures. One is with the sub data as already mentioned but in your case you should be able to access the memory directly by mapping it using `glMapBuffer`. This will lock the address so you should unmap it as well with `glUnmapBuffer`. Mapping the buffer in swift might be a bit hard to handle though but in languages such as C (or Objective-C) this is very useful for using `memcpy`.

So as long as you use any of these procedures you should not need to reset the pointer by calling `glVertexAttribPointer` as the pointer should be the same as it was. But even if the pointer persists I would not dare to keep it without setting it again. If nothing else this can produce issues later in development. Also this is not much of a performance gain.

As for the memory access and holding the pointer you can now probably imagine why you do need to call buffer data each time. The memory used by the buffer is on a separate location or even hardware. You may pass the pointer to the openGL directly from the memory with `glVertexAttribPointer` but no buffers can be bound to do so. If a specific buffer is bound then `glVertexAttribPointer` will accept a relative pointer in the buffer which is in most cases 0 `BUFFER_OFFSET(0)` though this is not the best approach. It is very common to use interleaved vertex data such as:

```
{
        GLfloat x, y, z;
        GLfloat texX, texY;
        GLfloat colorR, colorG, colorB, colorA;
}
```

Then for the color you would use the offset of `(3+2)*sizeof(GLfloat)`.

But in general when working with vertex data and manipulating them it is best to create a certain structure you will use. Unfortunately I have not yet played around with swift structures and its capabilities but using C structures you may create a very solid system of structures which you can modify as you please and will not break your code. Take a look at this example to get a better understanding:

```
union Vector4f {
    struct {
        GLfloat x, y, z, w;
    };
    struct {
        GLfloat r, g, b, a;
    };
};
typedef union Vector4f Vector4f;

struct Vector3f {
    GLfloat x, y, z;
};
typedef struct Vector3f Vector3f;
struct Vector2f {
    GLfloat x, y;
};
typedef struct Vector2f Vector2f;

union Vertex {
    struct {
        Vector3f position;
        Vector2f textureCoordinates;
        Vector3f normals;
        Vector4f colors;
    };
};
typedef union Vertex Vertex;

void generateBufferExample() {
    int numberOfVertices = 100;

    Vertex *data = malloc(sizeof(Vertex)*numberOfVertices);
    // fill data here
    GLuint bufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*numberOfVertices, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    free(data);

    GLuint positionLocation, textureLocation, normalLocation, colorLocation, alphaLocation;
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, GL_FLAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureLocation, 2, GL_FLAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)(offsetof(Vertex, textureCoordinates)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalLocation, 3, GL_FLAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)(offsetof(Vertex, normals)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, GL_FLAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)(offsetof(Vertex, colors)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(alphaLocation, 1, GL_FLAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *)(offsetof(Vertex, colors.a)));
}
```

The interesting part here is setting the vertex attribute pointers. Although the size is hardcoded (as it should be) the rest of the parameters are totally dependent on the `Vertex` structure. That means you may reorder, resize or even add parts of the `Vertex` structure during your development and the code will never break for you. You may even use the same structure to draw 2D vertex data and simply pass the size 2 in attribute pointer and it will still work.